# Memory leak in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, memory-leaks

I have the following code. It is an ActionMailer class method which sends email containing two kinds of attachments:

1. pdf file (_attachment), rendered in memory and added directly to the message
2. some other files (_attached_files), that can be added from file system.

Everything works perfectly, except one thing - it leaks memory. As long as users send messages with attachments, memory consumption keeps growing and and growing. It does not return memory back.
As far as I tested, I suspect that this problem is related to attached files from the file system, not rendered PDF file.

```
  attachments[_attachment.pdf_filename] = render(_attachment.pdf_template_path, :format => :pdf)

 _attached_files.try(:each) do |file|
      attachments[file.attachment_file_name] = File.read(file.attachment.path, mode:"rb")
 end

mail(:to =>_recipients, :from=>_sender_name, :subject => _subject)
```

Comment: I use Paperclip to store attachments.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, finally I have found the cause of the memory leak.
I was wrong - it was related to the pdf file.

I use prawn to render pdf files. I included incorrectly external font families and used them in the tables. Each time prawn generated table some amount of memory remained allocated.

Comment: Hi @tomukas, could you share more about your problem with Prawn and your solution. I face with memory leak currently, but cannot find any clue about it until I see your answer here. I also have specify the `font 'Helvetica'` in my Prawn document but I'm not so sure if this is the cause of my problem. Your response could be my great help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I use prawn 1.0.0.rc2

Comment: Try to update pranw version to latest master from github. It looks like this issue has been finaly solved https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/424

Answer (score 0):

I do a similar thing, except I do

```
  attachments[file.attachment_file_name] 
     = File.open(file.attachment.path, "rb") {|f| f.read}
```

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but it's worth a try

Comment: thanx RadBrad, but it didn't help.